# Is it possible for Flexbox to have responsive columns?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I wish to have an area in a web page that wraps responsively but constrained in columns.  I am trying to mimic behavior seen in Microsoft Windows Explorer - the right hand pane showing files in small icon mode.

**Example Of Windows behavior**
[image]

**Snippet showing flex wrapping but not constrained into columns**

```html
<html>
<head>
  <style>
    .container {
      display: flex;
      flex-wrap: wrap;
    }

    .item {
      background-color:red;
      margin: 10px;
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="item">Some Text</div>
    <div class="item">Some Text asdf</div>
    <div class="item">Some Text asdfasdf</div>
    <div class="item">Some Text asdfasdfasdfasdf</div>
    <div class="item">Some Text asdf</div>
    <div class="item">Some Text asdfsd</div>
    <div class="item">Some Text weqrqwerwerqw</div>
    <div class="item">a</div>
    <div class="item">aaa</div>
    <div class="item">aaaaa</div>
    <div class="item">aa</div>
    <div class="item">Some Text</div>
    <div class="item">Some Text</div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

The right-hand pane can be stretched larger or shrunk smaller.  The column count responds only showing columns that fit such that there is no x-overflow.  The items in the right-hand pane are justified top and left.  Notice the final item is in the left-most column, but on a row by itself.

I have tried `display:grid`, but then it tries to force a number of columns always.  This is not responsive, this is heavy handed.

Can this be achieved using Flexbox?  Can this be achieved with CSS or do I need JavaScript?

Comment: With Flexbox, e.g. as in the image, the items flows left-to-right. That mean you can dynamically get equal height per row but not equal width per column. For that you need a script, or make break points with media query's. If to use Flexbox with column direction (top-to-bottom), it is the opposite. Furthermore, since Flexbox has some issues when it comes to wrapping in column direction, CSS Columns might do a better job, so bottom line, the only tech. that works in both directions is CSS Grid, so make your pick...

Comment: Also, since Windows Explorer doesn't limits itself to a certain tech., but instead tries to do its job in the best possible way, why should you. As Flexbox has better support as of today, I would go with it, and add a tiny script that take care of the small things it can't...which kind of answers the question _"Is it possible for Flexbox to have responsive columns?"_ with a _"Yes, with some help"_

Comment: @LGSon - that is a reasonable request - mix technologies to get the experience desired.  I guess the point of this question is to determine the mix.  If Flexbox can behave as desired there is no reason to evaluate other technologies.  if it cannot, then I will need to look further...

Comment: Great...then I suggest you go with Andrei's answer, combined with the suggested media query's, and/or add a script.

Comment: @LGSon - yes I will use Andrei's answer.  Thank you for your advice...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're looking for:

```css
.item {
  flex: 0 0 210px;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

... where `210px` is your desired item width.

```css
.container {
      display: flex;
      flex-wrap: wrap;
    }

    .item {
      background-color:red;
      margin: 10px;
      flex: 0 0 210px;
      text-overflow: ellipsis;
      overflow-x: hidden;
      white-space: nowrap;
    }
```

```html
  <div class="container">
    <div class="item">Some Text</div>
    <div class="item">Some Text asdf</div>
    <div class="item">Some Text asdfasdf</div>
    <div class="item">Some Text asdfasdfasdfasdf</div>
    <div class="item">Some Text asdf</div>
    <div class="item">Some Text asdfsd</div>
    <div class="item">Some Text weqrqwerwerqw this will not wrap...</div>
    <div class="item">a</div>
    <div class="item">aaa</div>
    <div class="item">aaaaa</div>
    <div class="item">aa</div>
    <div class="item">Some Text</div>
    <div class="item">Some Text</div>
  </div>
```

- If you want your items to grow and fill up the entire available width, change `flex: 0 0 210px` to `flex: 1 0 210px;`.
- If you want your items not to have a width larger than a fixed width, just use `max-width` property.

For the record: 2nd snippet (referenced in comments), has 2 versions.

**a) the normal one** (correct, but not working in IE10 and below - see [flexbug 8](https://github.com/philipwalton/flexbugs#flexbug-8)):

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.item {
  background-color: white;
  border: 1px solid #f3f3f3;
  margin: 1px 5px;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  flex: 0 1 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
@media (min-width: 479px) {
  .item {
    flex-basis: calc(50% - 10px);
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    white-space: nowrap;
  }
}
@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .item {
    flex-basis: calc(33.33% - 10px);
  }
}
@media (min-width: 992px) {
  .item {flex-basis: calc(25% - 10px);}
}
@media (min-width: 1200px) {
  .item {flex-basis: calc(20% - 10px);}
}
body {
  background: #f5f5f5;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="item">Some Text</div>
  <div class="item">Some Text asdf</div>
  <div class="item">Some Text asdfasdf</div>
  <div class="item">Some Text asdfasdfasdfasdf</div>
  <div class="item">Some Text asdf</div>
  <div class="item">Some Text asdfsd</div>
  <div class="item">Some Text weqrqwerwerqw this will not wrap, no matter how long it is.</div>
  <div class="item">a</div>
  <div class="item">aaa</div>
  <div class="item">aaaaa</div>
  <div class="item">aa</div>
  <div class="item">Some Text</div>
  <div class="item">Some Text</div>
</div>
```

**b) the f**-up one** (partly incorrect - flex is only used for growing - but it works in IE 10 and below):

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.item {
  background-color: white;
  border: 1px solid #f3f3f3;
  margin: 1px 5px;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  flex: 0 1 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
@media (min-width: 479px) {
  .item {
    max-width: calc(50% - 10px);
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    white-space: nowrap;
  }
}
@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .item {
    max-width: calc(33.33% - 10px);
  }
}
@media (min-width: 992px) {
  .item {max-width: calc(25% - 10px);}
}
@media (min-width: 1200px) {
  .item {max-width: calc(20% - 10px);}
}
body {
  background: #f5f5f5;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="item">Some Text</div>
  <div class="item">Some Text asdf</div>
  <div class="item">Some Text asdfasdf</div>
  <div class="item">Some Text asdfasdfasdfasdf</div>
  <div class="item">Some Text asdf</div>
  <div class="item">Some Text asdfsd</div>
  <div class="item">Some Text weqrqwerwerqw this will not wrap, no matter how long it is.</div>
  <div class="item">a</div>
  <div class="item">aaa</div>
  <div class="item">aaaaa</div>
  <div class="item">aa</div>
  <div class="item">Some Text</div>
  <div class="item">Some Text</div>
</div>
```

Comment: This is a very promising answer.  A couple of points.  On example 1 - the columns are locked in at 210px.  If I have a large collection of items with very little text there will be a lot of wasted space.  On example 2, columns are not constrained on the last row (https://jsfiddle.net/9e4f7cLp/8/)

Comment: @barrypicker i added `@media` queries to the second example.

Comment: your updated second example seems to work really well.  I can't find any complaints.  Thank you for your advice...

Comment: @barry: since you're looking for complaints, I have one: I'm not able to pinpoint your research efforts and/or your coding attempt(s). Cheers and happy coding! :). Don't mind me. Just kidding. Note I've just replaced the shorthand with the actual property being changed, so it's clearer what's going on.

Comment: You got my upvote, but to keep it .... make IE play along :) ... hint: border/padding/box-sizing

Comment: @LGSon. for IE you'd have to add `max-width: calc()` inside each `@media` query, there's no other workaround, unfortunately.

Comment: @Andrei - My apologies if I came across as blunt or ungrateful.  Your answer is greatly appreciated and works really well.  I guess I have too high of expectations.  I have been researching Flexbox strategies for 2 days now on this objective.  I have seen many examples where people might say that is good enough, but i pass looking for a better solution.  Most examples show where 'item' is exactly the same size.  For my use, 'item' is rarely the same size which causes column issues.  At any rate, thank you again...

Comment: @LGSon, I've updated second example with a f**-up version of it that's supposed to also work in IE. I can't test it before 1.5~2hrs, as I only have Linux here. Let me know if it works as I think it does.

Comment: @AndreiGheorghiu Its fine...IE doesn't include padding in the same way the other browsers do, even if using `box-sizing`, so instead of `max-width`, add its value together with the margin in the `flex-basis: calc(% - margin - padding)` ... and when you get time to test, add a note about IE and why you used either

Comment: @AndreiGheorghiu Well explained here why to avoid `max-width`: https://github.com/philipwalton/flexbugs/issues/3

Comment: @LGSon all good, except IE10 and below ignore [`calc()` in `flex-basis`](https://github.com/philipwalton/flexbugs#flexbug-8)

Answer (score 0):

Just use flex-basis property and subtract your padding size on both left and right hand sides. Increase the flex-basis to 50% to 100% for lower devices using media query.

```html
<html>
<head>
  <style>
    .container {
      display: flex;
      flex-wrap: wrap;
    }

    .item {
      background-color:red;
      flex-basis: calc(33.3333% - 20px);
      padding: 10px;
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="item">Some Text</div>
    <div class="item">Some Text asdf</div>
    <div class="item">Some Text asdfasdf</div>
    <div class="item">Some Text asdfasdfasdfasdf</div>
    <div class="item">Some Text asdf</div>
    <div class="item">Some Text asdfsd</div>
    <div class="item">Some Text weqrqwerwerqw</div>
    <div class="item">a</div>
    <div class="item">aaa</div>
    <div class="item">aaaaa</div>
    <div class="item">aa</div>
    <div class="item">Some Text</div>
    <div class="item">Some Text</div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Using jsFiddle on this answer - https://jsfiddle.net/3t1v3h83/16/ - I notice the container has 3 columns which respond down (meaning if not enough room it goes to 2 columns, or even 1 column) but does not respond up (meaning If I stretch the container wider I only get 3 columns and the items themselves stretch - even when there is room for an additional column).  How can I make this add columns dynamically as the container is stretched?

Comment: Just use media query to specify the no. columns like this -
 https://jsfiddle.net/qrx3b7pt/6/

Comment: looking at your https://jsfiddle.net/qrx3b7pt/6/ , the columns are compromised when the panel is shrunk.

Answer (score 0):

We can use `flex-basis: 33.333%` (for 3 columns), then a `text-overflow: ellipsis` and `overflow: hidden`, along with `white-space: nowrap`, to achieve this:

[image]

Like this:

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.item {
  background-color: red;
  flex-basis: 33.33%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding-right: 10px;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="item">Some Text</div>
  <div class="item">Some Text asdf</div>
  <div class="item">Some Text asdfasdf</div>
  <div class="item">Some Text asdfasdfasdfasdf</div>
  <div class="item">Some Text asdf</div>
  <div class="item">Some Text asdfsd</div>
  <div class="item">Some Text weqrqwerwerqw</div>
  <div class="item">a</div>
  <div class="item">aaa</div>
  <div class="item">aaaaa</div>
  <div class="item">aa</div>
  <div class="item">Some Text</div>
  <div class="item">Some Text</div>
</div>
```

Or here's a slightly more responsive version, which will add/remove columns when possible, using `max-width` and `min-width`. The downside to this is the last item (on a row of it's own) doesn't size correctly.

[image]

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: flex-start;
}

.item {
  background-color: red;
  flex-grow: 1;
  max-width: 300px;
  min-width: 150px;
  flex-basis: 33.333%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding-right: 10px;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="item">Some Text</div>
  <div class="item">Some Text asdf</div>
  <div class="item">Some Text asdfasdf</div>
  <div class="item">Some Text asdfasdfasdfasdf</div>
  <div class="item">Some Text asdf</div>
  <div class="item">Some Text asdfsd</div>
  <div class="item">Some Text weqrqwerwerqw</div>
  <div class="item">a</div>
  <div class="item">aaa</div>
  <div class="item">aaaaa</div>
  <div class="item">aa</div>
  <div class="item">Some Text</div>
  <div class="item">Some Text Text Text Text Text</div>
</div>
```

Comment: 3 columns always is not how the windows explorer behaves.  It is responsive in the sense that if 5 columns fits, it will use 5 columns.  As the window shrinks it is responsive in that it reduces the number of columns.

Comment: @barrypicker I added another solution which is responsive to the width so it  adds/removes columns when possible.